# How to extract discriminator from tuple of classes in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, tuples

Given the following code:

```js
abstract class Fruit {
  abstract readonly fruitType: string;
}

class Banana extends Fruit {
  readonly fruitType = "banana";
  length = 2;
  color = "yellow";
}

class Pear extends Fruit {
  readonly fruitType = "pear";
  roundness = "very round";
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
  readonly fruitType = "apple";
  fallOfMan = true;
  hasWorms = true;
}

const fruits = [Banana, Pear, Apple] as const;


export type Fruits = typeof fruits[number];


export type FruitTypes = Fruits["fruitType"]; // This should be "banana" | "pear" | "apple"
```

Why am I unable to get the correct union of discriminators out?

Heres the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYlArgS0QG8BYAKAQVEhngSgFNgATAewDtkBPBAM1wIAqnAA70AXAmp42AcwDcZAL5kyKNBgBCwNtuAJ6ADwj02TDNnxEyFBs3Zde-CENEIAvAgBEIXTs8LyBGQTGQgAC3cEACYAilgWZBYoSM9OemREgHd-JRVSNXQEAAVGZMNjU3MnBBJA21YObj5LF3oU0WAoHLqWHFM2ekKPTwA3eihuKF7TbuVSVVRCgEFhYWD9IxMzLGram0YGh2bBETbh4FXg7ooeYAyAeR4AWW1I6Bx6WIQwtAB1JIAthgPO9Prl5vl2JBHJZgQgANpaHQ6AA0xVKaJWa3oAF1KBh4mxIAE8oZhElEBBTjtYW9TiweDCCGB4WwcACQOMcSSIWSKQgqa4LCdRHDhRAWZ5js5Tp5uQgAPQKhACMJ4DBgMK9ZBMBCcrw+ZHATwIAA+Xg6XTNXgu2M8QA

Comment: Do you mean `Fruits["fruitType"]` ?

Comment: @BenWainwright - That gives an error: https://tsplay.dev/Wyv7bw . `Fruits` is `typeof Banana | typeof Pear | typeof Apple` (the constructor types), not `Banana | Pear | Apple`.

Comment: I'm not saying its the solution, but I don't see "name" as a property anywhere in your code...

Comment: @BenWainwright - They're constructor functions. Functions have a `name` property. (I'm not the OP. :-) )

Comment: @mikeysee - Are the types of `fruits` and `Fruits` really want you want? The constructors (and their types)?

Comment: @BenWainwright Whoops! Yes indeed I did mean "fruitType". I have edited the question above. It now throws an error instead of giving me the expected union.

Comment: @mikeysee - Please avoid editing questions in ways that make the answers that have already been posted look weird. My answer referred to the `Fruits["name"]` part of your question. Removing it made the opening of the answer make no sense at all. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question as of when I answered it had:

```typescript
// Original code in question
export type FruitTypes = Fruits["name"];
```

`Fruits` is a union of the types of the constructor functions `Banana`, `Pear`, and `Apple` — the actual functions, not the types of the instances they produce. The `name` of a (constructor) function is always a string, which is why originally you were getting `string`. The updated question now gets an error, because those constructor functions don't have a `fruitType` member.

You can get the union you want using [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) to get the type of the instances those constructors create, and `"fruitType"` to access the type of the `fruitType` member of those instances:

```typescript
export type FruitTypes = InstanceType<Fruits>["fruitType"];
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYlArgS0QG8BYAKAQVEhngSgFNgATAewDtkBPBAM1wIAqnAA70AXAmp42AcwDcZAL5kyKNBgBCwNtuAJ6ADwj02TDNnxEyFBs3Zde-CENEIAvAgBEIXTs8LyBGQTGQgAC3cEACYAilgWZBYoSM9OemREgHd-JRVSNXQEAAVGZMNjU3MnBBJA21YObj5LF3oU0WAoHLqWHFM2ekKPTwA3eihuKF7TbuVSVVRCgEFhYWD9IxMzLGram0YGh2bBETbh4FXg7ooeYAyAeR4AWW1I6Bx6WIQwtAB1JIAthgPO9Prl5vl2JBHJZgQgANpaHQ6AA0xVKaJWa3oAF1KBh4mxIAE8oZhElEBBTjtYW9TiweDCCGB4WwcACQOMcSSIWSKQgqa4LCdRHCAJJEiDaWD0VoAHmFEDAAD54Z5js5Tp5uQgAPS6rw+ZHATwIAA+Xg6XXNXgu2M8QA)

Or you could be more direct:

```typescript
export type FruitTypes = (Banana | Pear | Apple)["fruitType"];
```

...but I'm guessing you're trying to avoid repeating that list (in the above and also `fruits`) for maintenance reasons.

Comment: Excellent! InstanceType is the helper I was looking for, thanks! :)